# React Router to render component outside of nav

Tags: reactjs

I've made a nav in the header, but when I click on the link it's rendering the component inside of that same header. So I'd like to render it under the header. What is the correct way to accomplish this?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import Home from "./Home";
import About from "./About";
import Events from "./Events";
var ReactRouter = require("react-router-dom");
var Router = ReactRouter.BrowserRouter;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Switch = ReactRouter.Switch;

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <img src={require("./img/logo.png")} className="logo" alt="Logo" />
        <Router>
          <div className="container">
            <Nav />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
              <Route exact path="/events" component={Events} />
              <Route
                render={function() {
                  return <p>Not Found</p>;
                }}
              />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: You have to place the <Nav /> outside the header div, the <Nav /> component will render where it is placed, you have it placed inside the header then it will display there.

Comment: Hey @Tenza my Nav is the navigation bar, so I want it in the header. I just want it to render the components under the header.

Answer (score 0):

The route is rendered inside the header because you put it between the `<div className="header"></div>` tags.
Edit your code to look like so:

```
// Imports

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="header">
          <img src={require("./img/logo.png")} className="logo" alt="Logo" />
          <Nav />
        </div>
        <Router>
          <div className="container">

            <Switch>
              // Routes... 
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I may have not asked correctly. The nav is just the links to the other components(pages) on the app, so it should be in the header. I really want the components to render under the header when clicked